# 「元気をなくすとは」meaning?

Tags: translation

Does anyone have insight into what 「元気をなくすとは」means? I am aware that 元気 is "energy" and なくす is "to lose". So "to lose energy" makes sense? However I am not altogether sure what とは means in this instance. A Japanese friend asked me for an English equivalent and I wasn't sure if this was colloquial somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Saying that 元気 is 'energy' is a gross simplification.

Comment: I am aware. As I am asking a specific question, I didn't have time to give an extensive definition. Do you know what it means in this instance or were you just making a general observation?

Comment: Maybe: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25329/7944

Comment: `I am not altogether sure what とは means in this instance. ` ← What instance?  You have not provided any context.  「とは」 can mean a couple of completely different things and only the context will tell what meaning it is used for.

Comment: @user3856370 - Thank you, that link was helpful!

Comment: @l'électeur - I am not sure of the context, but I will ask her. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“元気をなくす” means “lose energy”, “lose their health” or “being down”. You can use on physical matter and mental matter both.

Regarding meaning of “とは”:

It’s hard to say without seeing whole sentence but if that word is using like below it have implication that "you shouldn't". I think there are no words in english to replace it completely. I tried to find good example..

> 彼女に捨てられたくらいで元気をなくすとは情けない。
>   Don’t be so down just because she dumped you. How pathetic you are.

In this case, its meaning is similar to "～するなんて".

Comment: To me, 'It's pathetic how down you are just because she dumped you.' seems more natural and in line with the original sentence.

Comment: It could be. But I wanted to say, anyway there are no words to replace exactly.