# a question about とは

Tags: grammar

大辞泉 says とは is 格助詞 combined with は, but I came across a strange sentence

> サラリーマンから農家になる**とは**ずいぶん勇気があるんだね

My question is that since と is 格助詞, usually something before it must be a noun except for と placed before 言う、思う etc.

So why in this sentence,なる can be placed straight before と instead of nominalize it first
like adding a の to なる？

> サラリーマンから農家になる**のとは**ずいぶん勇気があるんだね

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25323/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24976/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83710/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65371/9831